# Estimating slope of regression using OLS vs Cov(x,y)/var(x)

Tags: regression, least-squares

Is there a difference between estimating the slope of a line using OLS vs calculating the slope using the formula Cov(x,y)/var(x) ? . If these methods are different, what are the advantages of using either?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we are talking about [simple linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_linear_regression), the formula you mention *is* the least squares solution. You can use it when the model contains intercept and only one feature, otherwise, you need the [solution for the matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares).